# How to validate the visibility using Page Object?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I am having few overlay's and some elements , where I should check the the visibility of these element. Is that possible to achieve through page object?My intention here is I have a method in my page and it should return the visibility true or false.
Here is my page file

```
class HomePage   
include PageObject   
span(:text1, :text=>'text1') #this has 10+matches on my page

  def getAvailabilityOf text
    return send("#{text}.visible?")
  end    
end
```

This is how I am calling from my step definition.

```
Then(/^I should verify the visibility of "(.*?)" on images$/) do |text|
  puts on(HomePage).getAvailabilityOf text
end
```

Below is the HTML.

```
<div class="box col2 review-box featured masonry-brick" style="height: 360px; background-image: url("https://stagingfiles.gamestakers.com/images/204/medium.jpg?1408991647"); background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
    <a href="/interviews/jeremy-spillmann">
        <div class="gradient-fade">
            <div class="featured-box">Featured</div>
                <div class="title">
                    <span>text1</span>
                    <h2>Jeremy Spillmann</h2>
                </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Below is the error I am getting .

> ```
> Then I should verify the visibility of "text1" on images
>   undefined method `text1.visible?' for #<HomePage:0x35798b8> (NoMethodE rror)
>   ./features/support/pages/HomePage_page.rb:67:in `getAvailabilityOf'
>   ./features/step_definitions/homepage.rb:45:in `/^I should verify the visib ility of "(.*?)" on images$/'
>   features\RINavigation.feature:6:in `Then I should verify the visibility of  "interview" on images'
> ```

I am expecting true or false to be printed on console.
In brief I am expecting page object way of implementing

> @browser.span(:text => "text1").visible?

Suggest me some work around

Regards, 
Avinash

Comment: @JustinKo Edited as recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the line:

```
return send("#{text}.visible?")
```

The page-object is looking for a single method called "text1.visible?", which does not exist. `send` is for making a single method call. It does not evaluate the string - ie it will not determine that you actually want to call a method and then with the returned value call a second method.

You could do the following:

```
def getAvailabilityOf text
  return send("#{text}_element").visible?
end
```

Note that `send("text1")` would just return the text of the span element. `send("#{text}_element")` returns the page object element, which would have the `visible?` method.

Depending on how you are going to use the method, perhaps you actually want the following, which allows looking for the text without the need to also create the accessor.

```
def getAvailabilityOf text
  return span_element(:text => text).visible?
end
```

Comment: Working perfectly as I needed

Answer (score 2):

I noticed something subtle in your question.

You indicated in a comment in your sample code:

```
span(:text1, :text=>'text1') #this has 10+matches on my page
```

You also added this requirement:

> I should check the the visibility of these element(s)

Justin's answer is exactly what you need to do to validate a single, unique element, but when you have multiple elements that have the same attributes and text, then the locator you want to use is span_elements, like so:

```
def getAvailabilityOf text
    return span_elements(:text => text)            
end
```

Presumably you would do some sort of validation on this

```
Then /^I should verify the visibility of (.*?) on images$/ do |text|
    spans = getAvailabilityOf text
    spans.each do |s|
        #Your validation code goes here
    end
end
```

This validation is not very granular as you don't exactly know which span element you are validating, so make sure to take that into consideration.